# Push notifications with GCM, Freshplanet ANE, Flash Professional CS6 and VB.NET

Tags: android, vb.net, flash, air, push-notification

I have created a Flash CS6 AIR for Android application with the Freshplanet ANE for push notifications. Everything seems to be working, but I am still not receiving the notifications on my device.

**Here is my Flash CS6 code:**

```
import com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.PushNotification;
import com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.PushNotificationEvent;

txtMsg.text = 'starting..';

var push:PushNotification = PushNotification.getInstance();
if (push.isPushNotificationSupported) {
    push.registerForPushNotification("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"); //Google project ID
}

push.addEventListener(PushNotificationEvent.PERMISSION_GIVEN_WITH_TOKEN_EVENT, onRegistered);
push.addEventListener(PushNotificationEvent.PERMISSION_REFUSED_EVENT, onRefused);

function onRegistered(event:PushNotificationEvent):void
{
    txtMsg.appendText("Registered with registration id:" + event.token);
}
function onRefused(event:PushNotificationEvent):void
{
    txtMsg.appendText("Refused:" + event.errorMessage);
}
```

This code seems to work, because when i launch my App on my device, my txtMsg field displays the event.token. A long string containing what Im guessing to be the unique device id.

My Android manifest looks like this:
    `

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
                <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
                <uses-permission android:name="air.it.test.PushTest2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
                <permission android:name="air.it.test.PushTest2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
                <application>
                    <activity android:name="air.it.test.PushTest2"></activity>
                    <receiver android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                        <!-- Receive the actual message -->
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                            <category android:name="air.it.test.PushTest2" />
                        <intent-filter>
                        </intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                            <category android:name="air.it.test.PushTest2" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </receiver>
                    <service android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.LocalNotificationService"/>
                    <receiver android:name="com.freshplanet.nativeExtensions.LocalBroadcastReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
                </application>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <extensions>
    <extensionID>com.freshplanet.AirPushNotification</extensionID>
  </extensions>
```

`

This is my VB.NET server application which sends the message to the device with the token received above.

```
Dim regId As String = "XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" device token id
    Dim MessageText As String = "Hope this works"
    Dim applicationID As String = "APP ID" 'received from Google API console as the Key for server applications
    Dim result As String = ""
    Dim SENDER_ID As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" 'same ID used in my actionscript file above - Google project ID
    Dim httpWebRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send")

    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json"
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(String.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID))
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(String.Format("Sender: key={0}", SENDER_ID))

    Dim streamWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())

    Dim json As String = "{""registration_ids"": [""" & regId & """], ""data"": {""message"": """ & MessageText & """}}"

    Response.Write(json)
    streamWriter.Write(json)
    streamWriter.Flush()
    streamWriter.Close()

    Dim httpResponse As WebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim streamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())

    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd()

    Response.Write(result)
```

When i run this function, it get a success message. So everything seems to work correctly, but my device doesn't receive anything. What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fresh Planet have many branches, try this which is more recent:

https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Push-Notification/tree/feature/famepop-withOptions

And you need change the JASON to send these values:

```
contentTitle   <---- this is the title
contentText    <---- this is the message
tickerText     <---- this is showed in the task bar
```

Answer (score -1):

This?

```
push.addEventListener(PushNotificationEvent.COMING_FROM_NOTIFICATION_EVENT, onPushMessage);
```

Comment: Please explain. If this is a line from the OP's code that you think is the source of the problem, explain why. If this is something you're proposing as a solution, explain how it fits in and how it resolves the problem. As it is, this is really more of a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) than an answer.